# goapp deploy - failed parsing input: app file conflicts with same file imported from GOPATH

Tags: google-app-engine, go

My GOPATH is set to

> d:\Mihai\Programming\Go\

and my project is structured like this

```
d:\Mihai\Programming\Go\ 
--> src 
-----> code.google.com
-----> tursibservice
```

### File conflict

When I try to deploy like this

```
cd d:\Kit\go_appengine
goapp deploy -oauth d:\Mihai\Programming\Go\src\tursibservice\
```

I get the following error

```
RuntimeError: 2014/09/13 12:52:12 go-app-builder: 
Failed parsing input: app file model.go conflicts 
with same file imported from GOPATH
```

If I change the `model.go` to `tursibmodel.go`, for example, I get the same error, only now it's complaining that the `tursibmodel.go` has the conflict.

### Successful deployment

When I deploy my app like this

```
cd d:\Mihai\Programming\Go\src\tursibservice\
d:\Kit\go_appengine\goapp deploy -oauth
```

I get a `Deployment successful` and everything works as expected.

So, if I'm deploying from within my app, specifying the goapp's full path, it works, but if I'm deploying from within the go_appengine path, specifing my app's full path, I get an error.

Any idea what's the difference?

Comment: What do the import lines inside model.go look like? And the other files in the tursibservice directory.

Comment: I don't have any import lines in model.go. I only have 3 structs declared inside that file. For the other files, it's something like `import ( "fmt" "net/http" "strings" etc.)`